# How to return items in a vector in O(1) run time

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector E that holds entries of strings that also have parameters of how many times that string appears in a text file. There is another vector S, that holds the indices of the top 3 strings in vector E.
My question is how do I get the top 3 entries in Vector E into vector S and return the top entry and the top three entries in O(1) runtimes

Comment: This hinges on, and may be made impossible by, what qualifies an entry for the top 3. I recommend adding the criteria to the question.

Comment: As you have described it, given an already populated `vector<pair<string,int>> S`, then use it to populate `vector<size_t> E(3)`.  It can't be done in O(1).  Not unless you can do a cursory scan of `S` first.   However, if you are populating E with elements one by one, you can use a variation of an LRU cache to keep `E` valid in as inserts are occurring into `S`.

Comment: ^which would be amortized O(1), depending upon details.